# Is there a function that takes a filename from the Image object

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm using the Movie Maker Library Timeline SDK Control 6.0 dll
And to add a photo you need a STRING of a file name. So far everything is fine
But I want to insert a function that gets an IMAGE object
But the library does not have a function that cables an IMAGE object
What I need is to get the file name out of the IMAGE object
That is: string fileName = image

```
  Image img = default;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string url = textBox1.Text;
                Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
                img = Image.FromStream(stream);
                axTimelineControl1.AddImageClip(trackIndex: 1, fileName :img.ToString(),
                    clipStartTime: axTimelineControl1.GetMediaDuration(img.ToString()), clipStopTime: 4);
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cables an IMAGE object"? Do you mean creates an Image object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a small bit of an "XY problem" here--you're asking the wrong question. Your `axTimelineControl1` expects an image's file name. This implies that it *also* expects there to be an image saved to disk with that file name.

But all you have is a remote image, behind some URL. `client.OpenRead(url)` downloads the image into a `Stream`, but you can't do anything with that directly.

So, you don't want to take that image, and put it into a WinForms `Image` object. Instead, you want to save that image to disk with a file name, and then give that file name to your `axTimelineControl1`.

You have a few options for doing that:

1) You could take the `Stream` you got from `client.OpenRead()`, turn it into a `FileStream` and save it to disk.
2) You could use the `WebClient` to download the image directly to disk, and then give the image's file name to the `axTimelineControl1`.

Let's do 2) instead. It'll save a few steps.

First, create the file.

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.Create(fileName).Close();
```

We're creating a "Temp" file here--these are meant to be treated as disposable. Note that Windows doesn't clean them up for you, so once you're done with it, your program should delete it. `System.IO.File.Create()` gives us a `FileStream` object, but we don't need it, so we `Close()` it right away, so that the `WebClient` will be able to write to our file.

Next, we download our image, and tell `WebClient` to save it to our newly-created Temp file:

```
// Defining my own URL here. Feel free to substitute your own.
string url = "https://derpicdn.net/img/view/2018/5/18/1735426.jpeg";
 using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
}
```

Now we have an image on disk, and we can tell the Movie Maker SDK Control where to find it:

```
float duration = axTimelineControl1.GetMediaDuration(fileName);
axTimelineControl1.AddImageClip(
     trackIndex: 1,
     fileName: fileName,
     clipStartTime: duration,
     clipStopTime: 4);
```

And that should do it.

The entire code listing:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.Create(fileName).Close();

// Defining my own URL here. Feel free to substitute your own.
string url = "https://derpicdn.net/img/view/2018/5/18/1735426.jpeg";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
}

float duration = axTimelineControl1.GetMediaDuration(fileName);
axTimelineControl1.AddImageClip(
     trackIndex: 1,
     fileName: fileName,
     clipStartTime: duration,
     clipStopTime: 4);
```

Don't forget to clean up your temp file!